# Problema na utilização de joins múltiplos usando OleDb (viual studio, c#) para conectar ao Paradox

Tags: c#, sql, exceção, paradox

Estou trabalhando com um código legado usando o banco de dados paradox. Em uma parte dele há uma consulta já implementada e funcionando:

```cs
string FUNCAUXatr= @"TA.bdTEMDEFICIENCIA,TA.bdDEFVISUAL,TA.bdDEFFISICA, 
                     TA.bdDEFAUDITIVA,TA.bdDEFMENTAL,TA.bdDEFINTELECTUAL,
                     TA.bdREABILITADO,TA.bdCOTADEF, TA.bdESTADOCIVIL,TA.bdGRAUINSTRUCAO,
                     TA.bdUFCNH,TA.bdPRIHAB";

string command = $@"select TF.*, {FUNCAUXatr}
    from TFUNCION as TF
    inner join TFUNCAUX as TA
        ON TA.bdCODIGO = TF.bdCODIGO AND TA.bdCODEMP = TF.bdCODEMP
    where TF.bdCODEMP in ({selectedList})";
    
[...]

OleDbDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
while(r.Read){...}
```

Agora estou tentando fazer um join com a tabela TFUNCESOC:

```cs
string comand = $@"select tf.*, {FUNCAUXatr}, tfe.bdCONJUGEBRASIL
    from TFUNCION as tf
    inner join TFUNCAUX as ta
        ON ta.bdCODIGO = tf.bdCODIGO AND ta.bdCODEMP = tf.bdCODEMP
    inner join TFUNCESOC as tfe
        ON tfe.bdCODIGO = tf.bdCODIGO AND tfe.bdCODEMP = tf.bdCODEMP
    where tf.bdCODEMP in ({selectedList})";
```

e o programa para com a exceção:
`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Erro de sintaxe (operador faltando) na expressão de consulta ''`

Comment: Este é o SOpt, por favor traduza sua pergunta ou pergunte no SO americano

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema botando parenteses ao redor do primeiro join (de acordo com essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305904/paradox-db-sql-multiple-joins)

a consulta final ficou sendo

```cs
string command = $@"select TF.*, {FUNCAUXatr}, TFE.bdCONJUGEBRASIL
                   from (TFUNCION as TF
                   inner join TFUNCAUX as TA
                       ON TA.bdCODIGO = TF.bdCODIGO AND TA.bdCODEMP = TF.bdCODEMP)
                   inner join TFUNCESOC as TFE
                       ON TFE.bdCODEMP = TF.bdCODEMP AND TFE.bdCODIGO = TF.bdCODIGO 
                   where TF.bdCODEMP in ({selectedList})";
```

:)